# using while in v-for vue js or stop v-for after v-if is true

Tags: vue.js, loops, while-loop, v-for

hey i have an array like this:

```
{
"id": 19,
"title": "jsj",
"orderName": "rendan",
"seller_id": null,
"totalPrice": "24000000",
"pricePaid": "4000000,20000000",
"paid": "1,0",
"dateNumber": [
    "12",
    "فروردین",
    "1400"
],
"arrayCategories": [
    "2",
    "3"
],
"paidDetails": [
    {
        "pricePaid": "4000000",
        "dateOfPayment": "1401/02/05",
        "paid": "1",
        "daysLeft": 3
    },
    {
        "pricePaid": "20000000",
        "dateOfPayment": "1401/02/20",
        "paid": "0",
        "daysLeft": 18
    },
   {
    "pricePaid": "20000000",
    "dateOfPayment": "1401/02/20",
    "paid": "0",
    "daysLeft": 25
   }
],
"priceLeft": 20000000
```

}

as u can see there is a 'paidDetails' Which itself includes three other objects,

and i've used v-for in my html elements like this:

```
 <tr v-else v-for="(project,index) in resultQuery" :key="'doctor'+index">
                            <th scope="row">@{{project.caseNumber}}</th>
                            <th scope="row">@{{project['seller']}}</th>
                            <td>@{{project['title']}}</td>
                            <td>@{{project['orderName']}}</td>
                            <th>@{{project.dateEnd+'-'+project.dateStart}}</th>
                            <td>کل:
                                @{{Number(project.totalPrice).toLocaleString()+' تومان '}}
                                <br>
                                باقی مانده:
                                @{{Number(project.priceLeft) ? 
                        Number(project.priceLeft).toLocaleString()+' تومان ':project.priceLeft}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p v-if="payment.paid==0" v-for="(payment,index) in  
                              project.paidDetails" :key="'daysLeft'+index" >
                                    @{{ payment.daysLeft+' روز' }}
                                </p>
                            </td>
                     </tr>
```

so my question is how can i stop v-for in the last td element (which itself is a another v-for inside the parent v-for); when payment.paid is 0 and payment.daysLeft is less than the others objects inside the paidDetails.

```
                            <td>
                                <p v-if="payment.paid==0" v-for="(payment,index) in  
                              project.paidDetails" :key="'daysLeft'+index" >
                                    @{{ payment.daysLeft+' روز' }}
                                </p>
                            </td>
```

i think what i need is a while loop but i dont know how to do it,
**any help would be appreciated**

Comment: Not sure about the answer but I do not recommend using `while` in a webapp: too risky to get an infinite loop overall, Web can usually be iterative.

Comment: We are missing some important code. The array `resultQuery` is not defined in the pasted code.

Comment: Why not create a computed property which contains the filtered version of your array, then just use v-for as usual to render it?

Comment: Is it possible to filter array inside another array in computed ? by the way i didnt print all the code because its too long , but im using this paidDetails in another td which is contain another table in a modal so icant changed it anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your template is for rendering data. Do not try and manipulate your data in the template. This is an anti pattern.

Format your data in the way you want it presented and then render the formatted data in the template.

Your best bet in this instance - as Lissy 93 mentioned - is probably to create a computed property and iterate over that in your template.

Read up on computed properties here:

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html

Comment: I think you are right , But also I think it is very bad for Vue that it doesn't have such a capability (while loop with condition) ..

Comment: I don't think so. To enable that capability would be to encourage poor design patterns. Separate your concerns and your code will be more scalable, maintainable and easier to test and debug.